# How to transmit data from php back-end to front-end bundled by webpack?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to apply front-back-separating model in my website.For the front end , I used the ReactJS bundled by webpack, while for the back end , I used the php to output data.I try to use AJAX to make it success.
The directory structure and ajax file likes this.
[image]

I don't know how can I write the relative path in the ajax post?

Comment: Use `/` to create a path relative to the site root, ie `/src/test_ajax.php`

Comment: do you mean I should change$.post('/test_ajax.php')?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: It seems failed...